# CSS Cursor [not-allowed] Not Working In Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with input fields as the cells. There is an option to add rows and one to delete rows. I want the first row's delete button to not work. It is not clickable. It is faded out. Now I want on hover, there is a `not-allowed` cursor.

But it doesn't work!

```css
.clonable .del{pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: not-allowed;  
    cursor: -moz-not-allowed;
    cursor: -webkit-not-allowed;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Merchant</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clonable">
        <td><input type='text' name='des1' required></td>
        <td><input type='data' name='d1' required></td>
        <td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0' name='a1' required></td>
        <td>
          <select name='m1' required id='m'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($merch)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name='t1' required id='t'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name='s1' required id='s'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($source)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td><button class='del'>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS CODE

```
$(document).on("click", ".del", function() {$(this).closest('tr').remove();}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where are you exactly stuck? what do you need our help for to use the `:hover` selector?

Comment: When I try what I showed you nothing happened. When I try to `:hover` the result is the same!

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that you are setting `pointer-events: none;` on the button. An element with `pointer-events: none` will not take part in pointer events but also will not change the cursor or state (see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/).

Removing the `pointer-events: none;` and disabling the button works fine:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".del", function() {$(this).closest('tr').remove();})
```

```css
.clonable .del{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: not-allowed;  
    cursor: -moz-not-allowed;
    cursor: -webkit-not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Merchant</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clonable">
        <td><input type='text' name='des1' required></td>
        <td><input type='data' name='d1' required></td>
        <td><input type='number' step='0.01' min='0' name='a1' required></td>
        <td>
          <select name='m1' required id='m'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($merch)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name='t1' required id='t'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <select name='s1' required id='s'>
            <option value='' disable selected>Select One</option>
            <?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($source)){
          foreach($row as $value){
          echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";}}
          ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td><button class='del' disabled='true'>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: to add a crucial bit of information: The button will eb disabled because of the opacity. it is rendered last and will cover the elements and prevent them from being clickable. Same for links other other elements. A reason why disabling the pointer-event is not needed.

Comment: This doesn't help... I can click the button now! Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't click the button in my code example, what have you tried? Setting the opacity on it's own does not disable the button.

Comment: This is not all of my code... I have a js file. I think that may be the problem...

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code then? The issue is already reproducable with the snippet in the question so I am not sure what the issue is. Setting onclick on a button that is disabled and clicking on said button does not raise the onclick event.

Comment: @chingucoding Done!

Comment: @admin Does the snippet work for you or is there anything missing?

Comment: @chingucoding The snippet works but when I use it in my code, I can still click and delete the row...

Comment: Have you set disabled to true on your button as I did in my snippet?